# Why do I have two menu bars in my drupal instance?

Tags: toolbar

I noticed while I was building my theme, that I have 2 menu bars at the top of my screen, like so:

[image: I have two top bars in my drupal instance? how do I fix that?]

I don't see anywhere that would indicate there would be two.

How would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have 2 toolbars enabled. One is the Drupal 7 default toolbar which in my experience most disable in favor of the the admin_menu.

drush dis toolbar -y

or

drush dis admin_menu -y

Or under the modules config page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Administration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) issue about "[Duplicate Admin menu?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1250302)", which is fairly similar to what you asked.

[Solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/1250302#comment-4870718) = disable core module `Toolbar`.